# Looking for thermostat with web interface, MQTT capability, not dependant on cell phone apps

Tags: smart-home, hardware, hvac

Does anyone make a thermostat with (ideally wired ethernet) or wifi network connectivity where the device has a web gui interface that can be accessed and programmed with a browser (ie not dependent on cell-phone app) and will interface with various home automation platforms using mqtt?

I could build a thermostat from an ESP8266 module flashed with tasmota plus some connected relay's and controlled with, say, home assistant running on a raspberry pi, but what I wouldn't have is a decent wall-mounted human interface / display showing me current settings, etc.  Anything that *requires* an app running on a cell phone is a total no-go.

Does anyone make such a thermostat?

Edit:  Based on a few comments posted here, let me clarify / expand.  First, I want a professionally finished device with a nice user interface when I want to manually adjust / interact with the thermostat.  This device would have the necessary temperature sensor and relays to actually function as a thermostat, with a display and buttons or touch screen.  If such a device can be "home made" or fabricated, I'd like to see an example.  Second, I want the thermostat to be network accessible, preferably hard-wired cat-5 but otherwise obviously through wifi, and be able to interact directly with the device through it's own web GUIl using an ordinary PC+browser.  Anything that requires the use of a cell phone app is not desirable since I don't own a cell phone (and phone-based apps that interact with devices typically go through cloud-based external servers and this is something that I absolutely do not want to do).

Comment: yes, a few hobbyists have made such a thermostat ... do you have any questions that are not a poll?

Comment: `Anything that requires an app running on a cell phone is a total no-go` ... you are not thinking clearly ... everything on a cell phone is an app ... look at the demo at https://opensprinkler.com/ to see an example of what can be done using a web server

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the [HestiaPi](https://hestiapi.com/)?

With this you can use your laptop to connect to the built in Access Point to do the initial configuration. Has a touch screen interface, and can do MQTT.

EDIT: This thermostat does not require a cloud server to be able to access it remotely. It has a web interface that can be used to review the data, make changes, ect.

Comment: The original poster was looking for a thermostat, but the page you link is for linking IoT devices... you're going to have to put in a bit more effort to explaining how this answers their question.  Please [edit] in more detail on how this API will help the OP, and how they would integrate it with whatever thermostat you are suggesting (which should also be explicit).  Thanks!

Comment: This is an open sourced Thermostat. So it is exactly what the OP was looking for. I know this is my first post, but I know about this as I installed it for a friend that uses Home Assistant with it due to it does not require a cloud connection to access (Again, what the OP is looking for)

Comment: Apologies I failed to grasp that during my cursory look at the website, and the post in its then-current form lacked necessary detail.  A fully expanded answer is definitely preferable for clarity's sake, and given the recent edit I'm removing the post notice.  Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what country you're in, so that may effect the answer, but in the UK there is a company called [The OWL](https://www.theowl.com/), and their Intuition products are smart thermostats which *can* work without the Internet (one of my original requirements) as well as having an interface which allows direct control. It's the most 'open' thermostat I could find.

They have an app as well as an online dashboard you can log in to for the same functionality as the app. There's no web UI built into the hardware itself unfortunately, but what it does have is an option to set a UDP Multicast IP, and get keys (from the online UI) for the hardware's API.

In the kit you'll have 2 items (at least for the heating), the thermostat itself which has 3 simple buttons and a couple of indicator LEDs, and a Network OWL which connects to the LAN. They communicate over, I think, Zigbee AFAIK (don't quote me on that).

Once you've got UDP Multicast set up you can receive a feed of XML readings from the thermostat every few minutes telling the desired and current temperatures, whether it's running the boiler, etc. I got this hooked up quite simply with Node-RED (after writing a more complicated script in Ruby) and dumped to a DB & MQTT. I was able to find [an NPM module for it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/owlintuition) now.

There is also an API to push an XML command into it to change the controls, but I didn't have time to get that part working when I had mine.

Comment: OWL Intuition products appear to be cloud-based, which the OP absolutely does not want.

Comment: I perhaps wasn't clear in my answer, but although there is a cloud-based service, once the UDP Multicast interface has been enabled (a one-time task, through the cloud-based dashboard) then the device can be completely shut off from the outside world and can be controlled through the UDP Multicast interface.

It's not the most user-friendly mechanism, but I haven't found for resilience to lack of connectivity.